# How to query partitionkey in Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Azure Cosmos DB for NoSQL.  I made a container with a partitionkey called 'pricedate' but not really.  It's really called '/pricedate' because it's required to have the slash.  How do I query it in python with `azure.cosmos` version 4.3.0 library?

I've tried:

```
x=container.query_items("select * from container c where c.pricedate='2018-04-01'", enable_cross_partition_query=True)
x.next()
```

Got a `StopIteration` error

```
x=container.query_items("select * from container c where c./pricedate='2018-04-01'", enable_cross_partition_query=True)
x.next()
```

Got a `CosmosHttpResponseError` for incorrect syntax around the `/`

```
x=container.query_items("select * from container c where c.\"/pricedate\"='2018-04-01'", enable_cross_partition_query=True)
x.next()
```

Got a `CosmosHttpResponseError` for incorrect syntax again.

For extra info...

```
x=container.read_all_items()
x.next()
```

returns:

```
{'id': '2018-04-01T04:00:00+00:00',
'da': 'full',
'rt': 'full',
'/pricedate': '2018-04-01',
'_rid': 'mu0HAOqArvIBAAAAAAAAAA==',
'_self': 'dbs/mu0HAA==/colls/mu0HAOqArvI=/docs/mu0HAOqArvIBAAAAAAAAAA==/',
'_etag': '"0600755a-0000-0100-0000-63692d300000"',
'_attachments': 'attachments/',
'_ts': 1667837232}
```

so there is definitely data that matches the query and it is all lower case.

Comment: What does the `StopIteration` error show/mean? Which SDK are you using?

Comment: Yeah, the SDK information might help others, if you can add that to the question it would be great :) Do you expect items with that `pricedate` value? Is the attribute name correct (casing)?

Comment: The property name does *not* have a slash (`/`) character. That's part of the path, starting at the root ( `/`), when you specify your partition key's location within your documents. You have to provide the slash when specifying the partition key, since it could be, for example, `/item/pricedate` which would be accessed as `c.item.pricedate`.

Comment: Also: you don't need the word `container` in your query. Just the alias (`c` in this case)

Comment: No - just `c.pricedate`. If you are seeing actual `/` in your property names, then you have an error when writing data. You should edit your question to show how you create documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you define a partitionKey it forces it to begin a slash leading, at least, me to think that when inserting actual data that the slash continues to need to be used.  That turns out not to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

`StopIteration` is a documented signal of Azure SDKs for Python: https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/azure-core/azure.core.paging.pageiterator?view=azure-python#methods

[image: Screenshot of documentation explaining that StopIteration is raised when no more results]

This means the query is not finding any results.

Based on your comments, you are not finding results on the Portal either, which means the Python SDK is behaving as expected (not finding results).

Based on the updated question with the document, the problem is the property name in your document. You are using "/pricedate" as the property name, which ideally should be "pricedate" (this matches your query).

Either change how you are writing your documents to use "pricedate" or if you can't, then change the query to:

```
select * from container c where c["/pricedate"]='2018-04-01'
```

Comment: No, the query in the portal doesn't work either.  Yes the casing is correct.

Comment: If the Portal query doesn't work either (finds no results) then the behavior of the Python SDK is correct, StopIteration means it also finds nothing.

Comment: The problem is your attribute name, you have "/pricedate" in the document. Why not "pricedate"? Why do you need the "/"? If you change the property name on the document, the query should succeed.